# Cloud-init fails on 'ssh-authkey-fingerprints' module

Tags: cloud, cloud-init

I'm trying to pick up on Puppet a bit, however, I'm having trouble simply bootstrapping containers (not even to bootstrapping them with the puppet information). In my [cloud-init yaml file](https://gist.github.com/Battleroid/d2deca1f06902874f6ccc6c3f6916e4c) I've defined a basic user with a public key. I'm trying to start a Ubuntu 16.04 container using that userdata, unfortunately it fails citing that the [ssh-authkey-fingerprints module failed](https://gist.github.com/Battleroid/d9e9be90a8c757eb70595f6bbfdbba31).

I have the cloud-init package installed on the host (Ubuntu 16.04), the module most certainly exists at the location it is requesting, so I'm not sure what is going on here. I've tried just about everything to get it functioning but I have no idea what is going on.

If someone can lend me a hand or suggest something I'd appreciate it big time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire problem was I was only applying the profile I made for the user-data, I wasn't applying the default profile as well which setup the devices list.

I found this after looking in the syslog of the container I was creating. It reported the cloud-final service wasn't able to reset the devices list. So I checked the profiles and go figure, the default profile is of course the one that sets up the default networking devices.

That's all it was. After I applied both the default and separate profile with the user-data everything is fine! Sorry for wasting everyone's time.